# Jenkins build on last changed revision

Tags: windows, powershell, svn, jenkins

I have a build which is triggered by a change of the revision of the root of the repository. Unfortunately I only want a build, when a specific subdirectory is changed. The specific directory holds the source code.
1) In other words I want a build only when "Last Changed Rev:" of a specific directory is changed.
2) If the revision is changed I would also like to check if some files have changed and make a special build if that is the case.
How is that done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create two projects in Jenkins.

First one uses as code base only the directory that you need to monitor in order to trigger a build. And you configure Jenkins to trigger a build a any changes.

Second one uses the whole code base. But you configure it to be a child of previous project and to build it only when parent get updated.